# How to you draw a line segment from 3D to 2D in THREE.js?

Tags: three.js

I am trying to draw a line segment from a point a 3D scene to point on a HUD UI. One end of the line segment is specified in 3D e.g. (1.232, -34.12, 4.21) but the other I want to specify in 2D pixel coordinates e.g. (320, 200).

How can I convert the 2D coordinate to a 3D point and have it remain at those pixel coordinates as the camera (Perspective) moves? Initially I thought of taking the 2D position and projecting it onto the near view frustum maybe that would work, but wasn't sure how to do it or if there was a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3(320, 200, 0.5);
vector.unproject(camera);
```

will return in `vector` a 3D point which you can use to draw.
If you keep unprojecting as the perspective camera moves you are guaranteed that the 2D point will seem not to move in your HUD.

Comment: Thank you, assuming 0.5 here is the near frustum distance.

Comment: as per the 0.5 you can read more info at http://barkofthebyte.azurewebsites.net/post/2014/05/05/three-js-projecting-mouse-clicks-to-a-3d-scene-how-to-do-it-and-how-it-works